# Android storing RSA public Key

Tags: android, key, rsa

I've got a file with a public key from the server I want to communicate with.
Now I have a problem with storing the file in my App.
Is there any other way than reading the public key from the file?
I'm always getting a java.io.FileNotFoundException.

I tried to hardcode the key as a String and then pass it as:

```
Byte[] keyBytes = publicKey.getBytes();
```

but that didn't work out for me.

My code so far is:

```
File pubKeyFile = new File("keyFile/public.der");
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(pubKeyFile));
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) pubKeyFile.length()];

        dis.readFully(keyBytes);
        dis.close();

        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey)keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

By now I think I'm doing terribly wrong, but I can't figure out a better way.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can get the absolute path of the file that is not being found. Try something like `pubKeyFile.getAbsolutePath()` , and see if the file is really there.

Comment: I tried to put the absolute path to new File("absolute Path") but it still threw a FileNotFoundException

Comment: If you do `System.out.println(pubKeyFile.getAbsolutePath())` , what does it print? Does it match your "keyFile/public.der" location?

Comment: You could always hardcode the key as a base64-encoded string, or an simply a hard-coded but somewhat uglier `byte[]`.

Comment: The base64-encoding tip worked for me! Thanks a lot